# Getting OAuth2 token using username&passowrd grant type

Tags: python, azure, adal

I am using the following adal library in order to fetch Oauth2 token (AAD).

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python

The following code does work and i can get my token:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/certificate_credentials_sample.py

But in my specific case i want to be able to fetch the token with providing username and password (password grant type)

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's not well documented but user/password authentication is still available in latest (0.4.4)

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common')
context.acquire_token_with_username_password(
    'https://management.core.windows.net',
    'me@outlook.com',
    'password',
    '04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46')
```

See for reference: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/adal/authentication_context.py#L128-L145

Answer (score 0):

The library for some reason removed possibility to perform authentication using username password, in latest version.

however use 3.13.8.999 this version of the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory nuget package, which is not the latest but has exactly what you need.

and then just go like this

```
string tenantname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];

string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantname}";
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);

string username = $"{UserName}@{tenantname}";
var userCred = new UserPasswordCredential(username, Password);

 AuthenticationResult authResult = await   authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(clientId, clientId, userCred);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, can i do the same in python with lowering the package version?

Comment: i think so. but i am no python expert.. although have done it in c# very recently.